# c#: Element 'Id' does not match any field or property MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this Bson model in mongodb:

```
"setting|resources" : {
                    "Name" : "EsupHamrah",
                    "Id" : "449ea0e1-0261-4bee-b096-a838746c94ea",
                    "Children" : [..
```

I have created this contract model :

```
public class SettingResources
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement]
        //[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        //[BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(CombGuidGenerator))]
        //public string Id { get; set; }

        public IList<object> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

When i do query I got tthis error:

```
An error occurred while deserializing the configs property of class ConsoleMongoApp.Applications: An error occurred while deserializing the values property of class ConsoleMongoApp.Configs: An error occurred while deserializing the resources property of class ConsoleMongoApp.Values: Element 'Id' does not match any field or property of class ConsoleMongoApp.SettingResources.
```

The `Id` is just string, not GUID or ObjectId but why mongo can not do map the id?

Comment: @user9405863 no, i've just commented `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]`.With this i still got above error.

Comment: did you try removing [BsonElement] annotation?

Comment: @user9405863 yes but nothing is change and i still have error on id.Seems mongo has a problem on `Id` element.

Comment: add [BsonIgnoreExtraElements] to class SettingResources  and i think you would be good

Comment: @user9405863 ,No I need this element.I added `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` for testing and error was gone but i got id = null;

Comment: did you try BsonClassMap?

Comment: @user9405863 No , I thought this field was a simple string and I should not be in trouble.

Comment: i think you need to set Guid instead of string.public Guid  Id{ get; set; }

Comment: @user9405863 I do that `public Guid Id { get; set; }` but i got this error: `An error occurred while deserializing the values property of class ConsoleMongoApp.Configs: An error occurred while deserializing the resources property of class ConsoleMongoApp.Values: Element 'Id' does not match any field or property of class ConsoleMongoApp.SettingResources.`

Comment: @user9405863 because id is string , not guid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your model in mongodb is wrong, there is a | (pipe) in Json string, try fix it on **"settingResources"**:

```
"settingResources" : {
                    "Name" : "EsupHamrah",
                    "Id" : "449ea0e1-0261-4bee-b096-a838746c94ea",
                    "Children" : [..
```